# Cannot pickle/dill a keras object

Tags: python, keras, pickle, dill

I am trying to serialize an object in `dill`:

```
import dill
import keras
with open('temp.pkl', 'w') as f:
    dill.dump({'clf':keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=20.0)}, f)
with open('temp.pkl', 'r') as f:
    d = dill.load(f) # errors here
```

An error occured that I've never seen before:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'keras.backend.mxnet_backend.get_optimizers.<locals>.RMSprop'>: it's not found as keras.backend.mxnet_backend.get_optimizers.<locals>.RMSprop
```

What does it mean by it's not found as [long path here]?

Note: To reproduce this, one needs to install `dill` and `keras`.

**Extra fun fact:**

If I use `tensorflow`'s custom keras api:

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
with open('temp.yml', 'wt') as f:
    yaml.dump({'clf':tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop}, f)
...
```

It works fine.

Comment: In the first case you are pickling an instance, it seems, and in the second you are pickling the class.  Presumably pickling the class is less error-prone as the pickle module can just look it up using the path, but if the `RMSprop` constructor is doing something funky (like loading an object from another location), pickle may not have enough information to reconstruct the object.